# Local search using the min-conflicts heuristic for solving a maze

Tags: java, search, artificial-intelligence, maze

I have a maze (represented in a 2D matrix) like below (5 x 5):

```
s 1 X 1 X
1 X 1 1 1
1 1 X 1 X
X 1 G 1 X
1 1 1 1 1
```

where s is the starting position, G is the goal position, and X is an obstacle.

How can I apply local search using min conflict heuristics in that maze.

What I am thinking is using Obstacles as "conflicts" and

```
1. Start at the starting position, current = start;
2. Find the neighbor that has least number of neighboring obstacles (conflicts), 
3. Update current to that neighbor state, and
4. Repeat until goal is found.
```

For simplicity, I can only move left, right, up or down ; but no diagonal

Am I doing it right? If somebody here can point me to the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely valid algorithm for solving a maze. If someone told you that you had to use min conflicts as your heuristic, I think it's probably the best approach, as it has some nice properties of avoiding dead ends. However, I'm not sure it will be particularly efficient. It is very easy to construct a maze that it would handle sub-optimally, for instance:

```
s 1 1 1 1
X 1 X X X
X 1 X G 1
X 1 X X 1
X 1 1 1 1
```

At the crux of it, min conflicts is just kind of a strange heuristic to use for a maze. It is designed to be used for problems in which whether or not an answer solves the problem is completely determined by whether or not it conflicts with any rules (N-Queens, for instance). In these problems, reducing the number of conflicts inherently means that you are closer to a working solution. That's not the case for a maze - the only thing that determines whether or not you have a solution is whether or not you are at the goal. You might have to go through a tunnel of obstacles to get there. So while technically correct, this doesn't seem like an ideal approach.